# histogram of a wide (but specific) x range in r

Tags: r, histogram, facet-wrap

I'm trying to present a histogram using ggplot which range between 160 to 490(values) in different sites using facet_wrap, the values are not constant between the sites. I Tried different approaches but without success (also to treat it a bar plot)...
first, it tell me that x variable is discrete. perhaps you want stat="count"?
It gives me a lot of values in the x axis...
what do I miss?
thanks

Comment: please provide code that shows what you've tried and what went wrong.  You can embed code when asking questions by highlighting the code and ctrl-K.

Comment: I tried this:
ggplot(data, aes(x= ))+
    geom_histogram(na.rm = TRUE, stat= "count", color= "white")+
    facet_wrap(~plot)

Comment: and I got histogram facet by , but the x-axis is not readible, the results are deploited by many values and i can't recognize the bins (don't know how to add file)

Comment: edit your original question to put the code in it, this will help others answer your question.

Comment: hey everyone,
I'm trying to present a histogram using ggplot which range between 160 to 490(values) in different sites using facet_wrap, the values are not constant between the sites. I Tried different approaches but without success (also to treat it a bar plot), my latest code is:  ggplot(data, aes(x= ))+ geom_histogram(na.rm = TRUE, stat= "count", color= "white")+ facet_wrap(~plot)... first, it tell me that x variable is discrete. perhaps you want stat="count"? It gives me a lot of values in the x axis... what do I miss